# Place relative div on another div which fill that entire div

Tags: css, position, append

I have one `div` with class `main-div` and its sub `div` with class `sub-div`. `sub-div` contains some data. And I would like to append another `div` to `sub-div`  which should cover the whole `sub-div` like a mask. I like do this with `css`. But i didn't get the actual result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="sub-div">
        jhgsdfjgjsdgfjgsdfgsdf<br />
        ugsdfgsdfgsgfjdgjfsdgsdf<br />
        jhgsdfjgjsdgfjgsdfgsdf<br />
        ugsdfgsdfgsgfjdgjfsdgsdf<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-div{
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.sub-div{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.in-div{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    var html = '<div class="in-div"></div>';
    $('.sub-div').append(html);
});
```

As per my knowledge, if I place a `div` with in another `div`, and give `width` and `height` as `100%`, then it will have the width of the parent. Here when I give `position: relative` to `in-div`, it get the `width` and `height` of parent. But when the `position` become `absolute` or `fixed`, it broken.

My fiddle is  http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/wfhfyf4a/

**Current result is**

[image]

**Expected result is**

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `position:relative` to .sub-div, and a `position:absolute` to it's inner div (mask):

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfhfyf4a/2/)

```
.sub-div{
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
margin-left: 50px;
color: #FFF;
}
.in-div{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```

Comment: Wow...and that is the right answer..thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wfhfyf4a/6/

set the `position` to `absolute` of `.in-div` and add `top:0` so that the `div` align to the `top` of `relative` element

```
.sub-div{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
    position:relative; <-- added
}

.in-div{
    position: absolute; <-- change to absolute from relative
    top:0; <-- added
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfhfyf4a/5/)

```
.sub-div{
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.in-div{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```